# How to get Menu item in a specific css using Selenium and Serenity

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

I have the following html part from an application and I can't get to click/identify any of the Menu's drop-down elements.

All I can achieve is to click on the Menu and display the drop-down menu in Chrome, but can't iterate throughout it's elements. I have to click on any of the Menu's elements but I'm unable to correctly locate them.

This is how I identify the Menu by css:
@FindBy(css="#toplevel_menu li:nth-child(2)")

```
<ul id="toplevel_menu" style="width:1100px;">
                <li>
                </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="divider">Items</a>
                <ul id="items">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openDialog1">Element1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openDialog2">Element2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openDialog3">Element3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `#items` in the css selector:

```
#toplevel_menu #items li:nth-child(2)
```

To get all items: `#toplevel_menu #items li`